# Неправильный SQL синтаксис во время добавления записей в БД на сайт

Tags: php, sql

Пытаюсь добавить запись в БД с 5 столбцами (айди, фирма, название, ядра и частота),выдаёт ошибку:

Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Wanderer', '3', '1' )' at line 1 in C:\OSPanel\domains\lmAshv\BD\index.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\OSPanel\domains\lmAshv\BD\index.php(20): mysqli_query() #1 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\lmAshv\BD\index.php on line 20

Код

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database');
$connect->set_charset("utf8mb4");
if (!$connect){
    echo'Ты чево.........';
}
else{
    echo '<h1>Добро пожаловать!</h1>';
}

$result = $connect->query('SELECT * FROM `Ассортимент`');
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo '<p>ID модели: '.$row['model_ID'].', название '.$row['model_name'].'</p>';
}
?>
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["model_ID"])) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `Ассортимент` (`model_ID`, `firm`, `model_name`, `corenums`, `frequecy`) VALUES ('{$_POST['model_ID']}', '{$_POST['firm']}'), '{$_POST['model_name']}', '{$_POST['corenums']}', '{$_POST['frequecy']}'   )");

    if ($sql) {
      echo '<p>Данные успешно добавлены в таблицу.</p>';
    } else {
      echo '<p>Произошла ошибка: ' . mysqli_error($connect) . '</p>';
    }
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Айди:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="model_ID"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Фирма:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="firm"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Название модели:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="model_name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Количество ядер:</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="corenums"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Частота:</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="frequecy"> ГГц</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="OK"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Что не так? Полностью скопировал пример. З. ы. знаю что не так написал частота на английском, просто потом было в падлу менять

Изначально в конце было три скобочки, я думал кое-какие лишние потому что я не туда натыкал. Скорее всего, это добавило проблем в мой гвн-код. Ничего не помогло

Comment: Нет бы, как все нормальные люди, собрать запрос в отдельной переменной - давай собирать вотпрямсразу в вызове на выполнение, мы ж никогда не ошибаемся и надобности на собранный запрос смотреть у нас нету...

Comment: После $_POST['firm'] скобка закрывающая стоит, в этом и проблема

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в лишней круглой скобке. Вместо:

'{$_POST['firm']}'**)**,

должно быть:

'{$_POST['firm']}',

Но практика встраивания значений непосредственно в запрос порочна и чревата SQL-инъекциями. Есть же параметризованные (подготовленные, подготавливаемые) запросы.